# Create program that deletes a specific character in file

Tags: java, text, character, text-files

I am writing a program using Java that will scan a text file, then delete the "\n" character that eliminates the line separations in the text file.... I have already written the program that reads the file and prints in into another... Here it is:

```
import java.io.BufferedReader;

import java.io.FileReader;

import java.io.FileWriter;

import java.io.IOException;

import java.io.BufferedWriter;
public class test

{

    public static void main( String args[] )

    {

        try

        {

            BufferedReader br = new BufferedReader(new FileReader( "HumanProtein" ));

            BufferedWriter bw = new BufferedWriter(new FileWriter( "BIOIhonorsproject" ));

            String line;
            while ((line = br.readLine()) != null) {
                bw.write( line + "\n" );
            }
            br.close();
            bw.close();
        }
```

Comment: So whats your question?

Comment: What exactly is the problem?

Comment: Surely you just need to get rid of `+ "\n"`... although you should also use try-with-resources for `BufferedReader` and `BufferedWriter`...

Comment: I do not know how to create a program that will read a text file, edit the text file, and print it into another file.

Comment: By editing, I want to delete all the \n character in this file.

Answer (score 0):

Use [`String.replaceAll()`](http://docs.oracle.com/javase/6/docs/api/java/lang/String.html#replaceAll(java.lang.String, java.lang.String)) method to remove or replace a specific character in a string by using:

```
String replacedString = line.replaceAll("(\\r|\\n)", "");
```

Use [`String.trim()`](http://docs.oracle.com/javase/6/docs/api/java/lang/String.html#trim()) method to remove whitespaces (spaces, new lines etc.) from the beginning and end of the string.

```
String trimmedString = myString.trim();
```

Answer (score 0):

You can do this by writing the file to another file without writing the `\n` character.
so change the line

```
bw.write( line);
```

to

```
bw.write(line);
```

After that by using the same method read this file and write it to the first file and its done.

```
BufferedReader br = new BufferedReader(new FileReader( "HumanProtein" ));
BufferedWriter bw = new BufferedWriter(new FileWriter( "BIOIhonorsproject" ));
String line;
while ((line = br.readLine()) != null) {
      bw.write(line);
}
br.close();
bw.close();
br = new BufferedReader(new FileReader( "BIOIhonorsproject" ));
bw = new BufferedWriter(new FileWriter( "HumanProtein" ));
while ((line = br.readLine()) != null) {
      bw.write(line);
}
br.close();
bw.close();
```